# Magento 1.9 go to payment methods after cancel payment

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

I'm working on magento site which have code to show payment method, after some user went to payment and cancel it.

ex- user fills the checkout steps and go to paypal, when cancel the paypal payment he redirect to checkout page and show the payment method section.

i'm using magento default one page checkout.

i use this code

```
function onCompleteAjaxOpc(arg) {
                        shippingMethod.nextStep(arg);
                        fieldsetOpc.show();
                        jQuery('#opc-loader').hide();


                        jQuery('#top-shipping_method').on('click', function() {
                            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage/getShippingMethod'); ?>', {method: 'get', onComplete: function(arg) {
                                billing.nextStep(arg);
                            }});
                        })

                    }
                    new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage/getPayment'); ?>', {method: 'get', onComplete: onCompleteAjaxOpc });
```

but recently it stopped working

```
https://devsite.mydoman.comain/checkout/onepage/getPayment/
```

This ajax url getting 404 and not shows payment blocks, anyone know what coz this error, Thank You